# How to ommit pixelation of scaled canvas?

Tags: javafx, scale, tornadofx

I'm making paint program and when I want to scale the canvas ("zoom" it) I take this:

[image: SNAP]

How can i solve the problem?
Java: 1.8.0_191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get rid of this is to not use the canvas. I just don't understand why everybody wants to use the canvas. Why don't you use the scene graph? With the scene graph everything is vector based and can be scaled as much as you like. The canvas basically is just an image and if you scale up an image you get what you see.

Comment: If I could ask a question... I created GridPane (and FlowPane) with Rectangles. There's no the blur problem ,but I see that it consumes a lot of memory and CPU. Is there any more "primitive solution"?

Comment: This sounds obscure. A Rectangle is just a Shape and should not consume much memory and it should also not consume any CPU once its created. I also find it obscure that you use a GridPane or FlowPane for this but that is difficult to judge without seeing what you are actually doing. So please provide a small but complete example.

Comment: So I am creating a paint program. The GridView is something like Canvas. Each pixel in the GridView is a Rectangle. When i create 16x16 "image", there is no problem but when i try to create 512x512 one ,the performance problems appear. It takes long time to "start" the program and to repaint it when i zoom. (in that case program takes about 0.75GB RAM)

Comment: Oh no. You are really trying to paint pixels. Then I have put you on the wrong track. Sorry for that. Please stay with the Canvas in this case. You are facing a problem which has been discussed here before but I neither remember the headline nor the outcome of this discussion.

Comment: Ok ,i found the solution. In JavaFx 12 there is setImageSmoothing(..) method in GraphicsContext. Change to false fixes all. Thanks for help.​